# excel4node:How to lock a cell

Tags: node.js, excel4node

**using excel4node**

Is there any methed set some cells locked or other cells is not locked using the package, `excel4node`; I found `sheetProtection` can lock the Workbook, but I want to lock one cell or some cells. I've tried to find a method. I think locked cell missing in cell style settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, currently this is not supported. See [here](https://github.com/natergj/excel4node/issues/193)

> There isn't currently functionality to change the "locked" flag on a cell by cell basis. I can add that as an enhancement request.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53009804/excel4nodehow-to-achieved-add-datavalidationindriect    please!!!

Answer (score 2):

This is the workaround I use- it gives an error message when you try to edit a cell.

```
const lockCell = (worksheet, range) => {
  worksheet.addDataValidation({
    type: "textLength",
    error: "This cell is locked",
    operator: "equal",
    sqref: range,
    formulas: [""],
  });
};

eg, lockCell(worksheet,'B12');
```

Comment: Its giving repair error while opening the file in MS Excel and after repair fix , the cell becomes editable. However things are working fine in Google Sheets and Libre Office

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem.  After a little research I discovered that cell protection is part of the styles of a cell.  I had hoped that I could just modify the styles, but because the actual protection definition is a nested element and those are treated differently I could not.

There is now a [pull request](https://github.com/advisr-io/excel4node/pull/95) that has the necessary changes.  Hopefully, it will get merged, but if not you can copy them into your `node_modules` folder to get the behavior you desire (which is what I did).  Once those changes are in place, just create a new style and apply it to any cell you want to remain unlocked:

```
  const styles = {
    // Create a reusable style
    unlocked: workbook.createStyle({
      protection: { hidden: false, locked: false },
    }),
  };
  
  worksheet
        .cell(1, 1)
        .string(`test`)
        .style(styles.unlocked);
```

Then lock your sheet:

```
    const worksheetOptions = {
      sheetProtection: { objects: true, scenarios: true, sheet: true },
    };
    const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Test', worksheetOptions);
```