# excel4node:how to achieved add DataValidation"indriect"

Tags: excel4node

Is there any method to add DataValidation to the cell using the package, excel4node?

it can achieved in excel2013 to add DataValidation "=INDIRECT(AA9)"

I find **Methods Worksheet data validations ws.addDataValidation();** can add DataValidation, but how to add `"=INDIRECT(AA9)"`?

Comment: i want to achieved Two level linkage menu

Comment: OR Methods can add Formula Name Management ?